# Ionic 2 - Module cordova.plugin-vibration.notification does not exist

Tags: node.js, cordova, angular, ionic2

I'm having a problem here running `ionic emulate android`. When I run `ionic serve` everything works fine, with no error messages. But, when I try to emulate it... or even run it on my device, I get a white screen. When I enabled consolelogs, I got the following error:

[image]

I tried to install `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-vibration` again but it says it's been already installed.

Do you guys have any idea how I could solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried re-adding the platform ?

Comment: Yes, but it says `Error: Platform android already added.` :(

Comment: Note : 're-adding', so remove it and add it again

Comment: Now it worked :) yet, it doesn't display the component `<ion-tabs>` so I'm trying to figure out what the problem may be.